# How to search questions marked as favorites on SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, bookmarks

I do not think there is a way possible currently. So, this is also a feature request.

A)

> The number of favorites I have on SO
>   are increasing and it is difficult to
>   find a particular one that I am
>   looking for when I need it, defeating
>   the purpose of marking it as a
>   favorite in the first place.

B)

> Marking questions as favorites on SO
>   is a way of bookmarking that lacks
>   many things. For example - I cannot
>   categorize my favorites. It would be
>   excellent if I could tag them or
>   something (add a personal note as a
>   reminder? though tagging is better) so
>   that I can easily fetch the ones I
>   need.

C)

> I know I can do this by bookmarking
>   ALL the favorite questions in my
>   browser and tagging them there, but
>   that is just too much work. It can be
>   done here on SO itself in a better
>   way.

**What do you people think? Do you agree? Do you disagree? How do you tackle this problem?**
*Since I could not find a similar feature request here on meta, is there a way of dealing with this that I am not aware of?*

Comment: The option `infavorites:1` was implemented in August 2010, but [no longer supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test) since the new search was introduced early 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you bookmark them using external software, like your web browser, instead? Then you could categorize them into folders, search them, etcetera..

Comment: +1. Sorting and organization is already provided by the browser's bookmark functions. Therefore, duplicating additional sorting functionality within SOFU would be pointless. However, @Jeff, I do see some validity in being able to search on maybe `infavorites:1`. I think this feature would add value to an otherwise bland feature. Favorites is easier to use because it is only 1 click rather than 3 or 4 to put in a bookmark. Again, though, I agree that sorting and organizing favorites should be left to the browser's bookmarks functionality.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: yes thats what my point C says. But still bookmarking it on my browser has several downsides - syncing with all the browsers I use, they will be among a thousand other general bookmarks, bookmarking them at two places (on SO and the browser), its just too much of unnecessary work. If we can do that on the site itself, it saves a lot of effort and is a lot more elegant and maintainable. A "search as you type" sort of search for favorites would be perfect. Plus I do not see any downside of implementing it on the site. Is there any?

Comment: What's the point of a staring mechanism if it doesn't supplant outside bookmarking?