# Is there any way for searching favorites using IE, Opera, Safari?

Tags: discussion, search, bookmarks

I was looking for searching favorites when I found
[Ability to search favorites and questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27026/ability-to-search-favourites-and-questions)

An answer over there says

> There is a Grease Monkey script [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs-last-update-07-21-2009)
>   that should do it.

Well, then I went to [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs-last-update-07-21-2009) page.
The solution over there uses a script [so-bigbox.user.js](http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/so-bigbox.user.js) and says

> Install Greasemonkey for Firefox.

Is the solution limited only to FireFox?
**Any way for searching favorites using IE,Opera,Safari?**
Why is the feature not included in the website itself if there were so many request for the feature?

Please Note:This is not a duplicate question,
My question is "Is there any way for searching favorites using IE,Opera,Safari?"

*A list of requests in the past*
[Better Favourites Organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation)
[Add favourites tab after tag search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43736/add-favourites-tab-after-tag-search)
[Please allow users to sort their favorites based on tags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4379/please-allow-users-to-sort-their-favorites-based-on-tags)
[Tag Filtering/Searching for Favourites (closed)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14513/tag-filtering-searching-for-favourites)
[How to search questions marked as favorites on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44237/how-to-search-questions-marked-as-favorites-on-so)
[Search in favorited question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-favorited-question) *(It is tagged as `status-completed`)*

Comment: Status deferred: [Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality).

Comment: (As an aside, some nice reading: [balpha's thoughts on paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635).)

Comment: @Arjan: That comment explains the recent upvotes on that age-old post :)

Comment: @Arjan take a look at the javascript [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/careers-2-0-featured-listing-web-company-needs-successor-for-retiring-unicorns/81736#81736) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for installing the [so-bigbox.user.js](http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/so-bigbox.user.js) script on IE, Opera, Safari.

[How do I install a userscript?](https://superuser.com/questions/252046/how-do-i-install-a-userscript)